# Amount of executors in Storm

Tags: java, apache-storm

I'm playing around with Storm. This is a topology I'm using:

```
builder.setSpout("word", new RandomSentenceSpout(), 3);
builder.setBolt("exclaim1", new ExclamationBolt(), 6).shuffleGrouping("word");
```

I thought Storm would spawn 9 executors (3 spouts + 6 bolts) for this topology, but when I actually run it, I can see 11 executors are running.

What are those 2 extra executors?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about how you are counting the executors?

Comment: executor = parallelism hint .. (3+6 = 9) .. assuming he is using 0.8 distribution

Answer (score 4):

They are acker bolts which are responsible for managing acknowledgment mechanism. 
There is 2 ackers in your topology and each bolt task is equal to one executor by default.

storm uses acker as a bolt task (executor) and if we don't set Number of ackers, it will run some of them in the topology. if you want to exactly manage the number of executors, use the following :

```
Config conf = new Config();
conf.setNumAckers(1);
```

Comment: You can see number of ackers from the storm UI with the "Show System Stats" button. The fact that the listed number of executors wasn't adding up to the total number of executors was starting to driving me insane until I discovered this fact.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting numTasks somewhere else in the topology? Sharing the topology creation code shall be helpful to answer. Also, r u running this in local or Cluster mode?
Executors are always less then or equal to NumTasks. 
http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2012/10/16/understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-storm-topology/ This blog very well explains the parallelism in storm.